# Lighttpd getting 403 forbidden page

Tags: php, lighttpd

i have newly installed lighttpd in ubuntu 9.10
first it showed the detault page and i changed the permission of /var/www/ directory to 777
and now its saying 403 forbidden

my php-cgi -v

```
PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.7 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jan  6 2010 22:34:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

php -v

```
PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.7 (cli) (built: J
6) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

and i have added these line in lighttpd.conf file

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
                     "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                     "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
                 )))
```

still getting same error....

Comment: Logs. Always check your logs, you'll probably find an answer in lighttpd error log.

Comment: @rvs - lighttpd does not seem to log reasons for a 403, at least not out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the user you are running Lighttpd on doesn't have access to /var/

Comment: Why does it need access to `/var` when the docroot is `/var/www`?

Comment: This was the solution to the problem for me, however illogical it might sound.

Answer (score 1):

A couple suggestions about what might be wrong:

Permissions on the directory /var/www are 777 (a bad practice, by the way) - but are the subdirectories all readable by the web server?

Check your php error log and your lighttpd error log. (They may be the same file, depending on your php configuration).  Are there any errors in the log about permissions, or about anything else?

Is php-cgi running?  Check to make sure that it has permission to write to the socket in /tmp, and that lighttpd does as well.

Check your lighttpd configuration.  Do you have access rules that may be causing you to get a forbidden message?